# EventListener callback function not updating DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener

I have created a custom JavaScript function that is supposed to update the content of a specific DOM element (a `<div>` in this case) when a button is clicked. However, the content does not seem to be updating correctly. I can see the updated content in the console, but the changes are not being reflected in the actual web page.

I tried creating a function called `updateContent()` that takes an ID and a new text value as arguments. I added an event listener to the button, so that when it is clicked, it calls the `updateContent()` function with the appropriate values. I expected the content of the `<div>` element with the specified ID to be updated with the new text value, but instead, the content remains unchanged on the page.

Here's my code:

```
function updateContent(id, newText) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.innerHTML = newText;
  console.log("Updated content:", elem.innerHTML);
}

document.getElementById("updateButton").addEventListener("click", function () {
  updateContent("targetDiv", "New content goes here.");
});
```

When I click the button, I can see the "Updated content:" log in the console with the correct new value, but the `<div>` content on the page does not change.

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wyz0e8na/

Comment: Maybe something else in your page is undoing the change. You can use an element change breakpoint in the browser to catch it.

Comment: Or there is more than one element with id 'targetDiv' and the other 'targetDiv' is getting updated. getElementById returns the first matching element.

Comment: Following on with what @PhanisimhaNR said, you might want to console.log out the original value of elem.innerHTML to see what you're actually changing before you change it.

Comment: Add the html.... my guess is your button is submitting the page.